# The specified type member 'Items' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm making my project using code-first approach for the first time and I've never seen this error pop up when I was creating my projects using database-first approach.

*I know that there is a lot of these errors here but I've checked them and it seems that I need someone explain to me what is wrong in my particular example for me to understand it well.*

### Error

> The specified type member 'Items' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation
>   properties are supported.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: The specified type
>   member 'Items' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only
>   initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are
>   supported.

### What causes error

```
public dynamic List()
{
    var categories = db.Categories.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDateTime).Select(x => new
    {
        ID = x.ID,
        Name = x.Name,
        RootCategoryName = x.RootCategory.Name,
        ItemCount = x.Items.Count() // This line
    });

    return Json(categories, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

### Item model

```
public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int CategoryID { get; set; } // Seems like here I've done everything correctly
    public Category Category { get; set; } // Seems like here I've done everything correctly

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }

    public bool? IsAccessory { get; set; }
    public int? RootItemID { get; set; }
    public Item RootItem { get; set; }
}
```

### Category model

```
public class Category
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int? RootCategoryID { get; set; }
    public Category RootCategory { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<Item> Items { get; set; } // Here also it seems that I've done relations correctly

    public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

At first glance it seems to me that it is impossible to call something like `Category.Items.Count()` or `Item.Category.Name` using code-first, but I think I did something wrong with code because it should be possible. Please help, what should I do to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Category.Items` should be of type `ICollection<Item>` instead of `IQueryable<Item>`